# kubectl display all (pod name, container name) couples

Tags: kubectl, jsonpath

Suppose I have 2 pods podA and podB, each one having 2 containers.
I'd like to diplay:

```
podA containerA
podA containerB
podB containerA
podB containerB
```

Using jsonpath, I'm only able to display this kind of output

```
podA containerA
containerB
podB containerA
containerB
```

using this command:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.name}{'\n'}{end}{end}"
```

Is it possible to repeat the pod name, using only kubectl command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not.

There's no support for variable assignment so it's not possible to capture a value for Pod's name from the outer loop (`range .items[*]`) to access from within the inner loop once the inner `range` rescopes the pipeline.

I understand the intent in wanting to use only `kubectl` but this limits you to `kubectl`'s [JSONPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) implementation.

[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a more general-purpose JSON processor that is reasonable to expect|assume be installed by your users. It would permit capturing the Pod's name.

I don't have access to a cluster but something like:

```
FILTER='
.items[] 
| metadata.name as $pod 
| .spec.containers[].name as $container 
| $pod+" "+$container
'
jq -r "${FILTER}"
```